# Fast way to change IP address on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-xp

OS: WinXP, Win7

Is there any command line to change IP address/gateway IP/DNS easily? Either command to change directly or command to bring up this window (see below)? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You can do this with Netshell commands, I know you can... how? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use netsh.exe to make the changes from a command line. Here are a couple links to get you rolling.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468

http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm

Answer (score 2):

The best app for changing ip in win is http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm

something like network manager in linux

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Windows 7 32-bit. You MAY need to run this application as an Administrative user depending on your UAC settings.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/winipchanger/